# Is the double pronoun "it mine" correct in "You did it your way, now let me do it mine"?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, possessives, possessive-pronouns

I am a non-native English speaker, so I would just like to increase my knowledge of the language.

I heard this phrase in a TV show:

> You did it your way, now let me do it mine.

The ***let me do it mine*** part is hurting my ears. In French, you are not supposed to "retake" the same noun group twice.

Is the phrase grammatically correct? Why?

In my head it should be either:

> let me do it my way,

or

> let me do mine.

Comment: "You did it [in] your way, now let me do it [in my way]."

Comment: What do you mean by "retake," for us non-French-speakers? Note that "it my way" is not a single syntactic unit.

Comment: @alphabet He means "repeat" the same noun in the same sentence.

Comment: @fev Do you mean repeating the word "it"? OP's "corrected" version, "let me do mine," only avoids the repetition of *it.*

Comment: @alphabet No, it incorrectly presumes to avoid the repetition of both "it" and "way", but this cannot be. It is probably some confusion of the two.

Comment: In French, you are not supposed to do repetitions. retake is reprendre meaning here to re-use or repeat something (do it your way + do it my way or mine). Except that style rule applies to written French and not spoken French, necessarily.

Comment: @PeterShor You are correct, because _mine_ avoids the repetition of _way_ . But the OP's confusion seems be that _mine_ should avoid the repetition of _it_ too. In French the problem would be the same as in English: _Tu **l'** a fait à ta façon, maintenant laisse moi **le** faire à la mienne._  _Le/ l'_ is correctly repeated, just like _it_ in English. Although it is true that "faire" can be used without a direct object.

Comment: Thank you everyone ! It sheds some light on the matter. the "retake" I didnt know how to translate "Double reprise" where you are not supposed to refer with a possessive twice for the same idea (indeed in writing). 
For example : Il faut travailler les maths avec les élèves afin d’**en** faciliter **son** apprentissage, should be  Il faut travailler les maths avec les élèves afin d’**en** faciliter **l'**apprentissage. That's what I was trying to explain. 
I think I got confused with the  "it", what it refers to, and indeed mixed up that mine should refer to it as well.

Comment: It does not matter because he is referring to a whole noun phrase, which he had called noun complement, now changed to noun phrase (by fev?) : do it your way versus do it mine or my way. Mine is a stand-in for my way. In French, laisse-moi faire à ma façon and le faire à ma façon are not exactly the same. And by double possessive *he probably means* your way and mine.

Comment: I think i was making the mistake in french as well !! I would have said, Tu as fait à ta façon, laisse moi faire la mienne. Which is skipping the it of tu l'as fait. 
Anyway thank you for the help it was raking my brain !

Comment: In your title you say double possessive and now you are saying double reprise. In any event there is a reprise (your way and mine [my way]  but no double reprise. The "son" is just inaccurate grammar and "leur" would be too.

Comment: I don't think this is great in French: Tu as fait à ta façon, laisse-moi faire la mienne.

Comment: I thought there was. I think was just way off for everything..

Comment: Tu l'as fait à ta façon, laisse-moi le faire à la mienne. Voilà la répétition.

Comment: Now you have changed the title to double pronoun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct as you heard it on the TV show.

I don't know the context, so I can't say if ***it*** is a dummy pronoun or a personal pronoun referring to a particular action. ***It*** is the direct object of the verb ***do*** and being such a short word, its repetition in a sentence is acceptable most of the time.

What should not be repeated in the second clause is the noun ***way***, not because it would be grammatically incorrect, but because of what linguists call *[the economy principle](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=867d87a268b03f7c650a876c1a3560741f7faaca#:%7E:text=Linguistic%20economy%20principle%20is%20one,a%20system%20with%20high%20efficiency.)* (e.g. the least possible words to express fluent meaning). So normally we avoid redundant repetition such as:

> You did *it* your way, now let me do *it* *my **way***.

What probably confuses you is the presence of the direct object (***it***) next to the adjunct of manner (*[in] **your way*** and *[in] **mine***). Here is an example of symmetrical structure with only the direct object following the verb:

> You did your job, now let me do mine.

In this case, ***now let me do mine***, would be correct. But in your example, you cannot expect ***mine*** to replace both ***it*** and ***way***.

Comment: I doubt that it is a dummy pronoun here.

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed it was referring to a specific action.  (The mandalorian S3. E6 for reference!)
It was indeed the it next to mine that was problematic for me. I now understand better. Thank you :)

Comment: Repetition in speech is very common and not a mistake. So, I disagree with that  particular prescriptivism. It is easy to imagine: do it your way and do it my way. When people speak they aren't thinking of grammar or style principles...

Comment: @Lambie Which is why I included in my answer, _not because it would be grammatically incorrect_.

Comment: Yes, but you moralize against it by citing that economy principle.

Comment: Nit-picking, are we? I only mentioned the reason for the tendency of avoiding repetition in general.

Comment: I can only go by the actual language you used. And I do not think there is a "tendency of avoiding repetiition in general". Anyway, if all this is nitpicking, you have the right to that opinion. I do not quesiton that at all.